# Prototype Event to copy event objects to window.event for FireFox

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, prototype

Is there any way, using prototype or other means, to make events copy themselves into the global space (`window.event`)?

My problem is that I'm using a remote script that does not pass me the event object to my callbacks. Chrome and IE always have access to `event` and event `window.event`, but FireFox has neither, unless passed (and set) explicitly, so I was wondering if there was a way to prototype event objects to copy themselves into the global space.

Comment: Copy is really the wrong word. Store a reference in the global space, is what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case, the following line gets the `event` object in FireFox properly:

`var event = event || window.event || arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0];`

I went digging and found it there. For anyone in a similar situation that this doesn't work for, look through the whole `arguments.callee.caller.arguments` array, and if it's not there, refer to Andy's answer, where you can set `window.event` or any other global variable to the `event` object. That should work no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach event listeners to the window object directly by doing the following:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   // here's where something useful happens...
   alert(e);
}, false);
```

See this good post for information on event bubbling.  [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)  Hope that helps.

Andy